# Kotlin - getting random Int between 1 and 2 doesn't work with Android

Tags: android, kotlin

```
listOf(1, 2).random()
```

In IntelliJ IDE, this gives me sometimes 1 and sometimes 2

But when I run it in Android App, this gives ALWAYS 1! I tried it at least 10 times!

Next one:

```
(1 until 3).random()
```

In IntelliJ IDE, this gives me sometimes 1 and sometimes 2

But when I run it in Android App, this gives ALWAYS 1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Kotlin are you using? There was a bug in *1.6.21* on Android (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52618/) where Kotlin's default `Random` would produce the same sequence of values every time you ran the app. It's fixed in *1.7.20*, or you could use the Java implementation (`java.util.Random`). Maybe something like this:

```
import kotlin.random.asKotlinRandom

fun main() {
    val rnd = java.util.Random().asKotlinRandom()
    // using the Java Random as the source of randomness
    listOf(1, 2).random(rnd)
}
```

If you're on the newer version where it should be fixed, make sure you definitely *are* only getting *1*s - it's unlikely you'd randomly get *1* every time, but it's not *impossible*, especially with only two possible outcomes. So test it with lots of attempts, ideally with a bigger pool of possible results so you can be more confident you're not just getting unlucky with a coin flip here